# Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i update my android studio from 2.2.2 to 3.1.2 and when i sync my previous project i got following error. what's the problem guys. what i am doing wrong ?

Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:

The project 'TestProject' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
    **Upgrade plugin to version 3.1.2 and sync project**

The project 'TestProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    **Gradle settings**

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
    **Apply Gradle plugin**

Comment: Post your app level and project level gradle files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`google()` method was only added to `RepositoryHandler` only in Gradle 4.0. Update your Gradle wrapper to use more recent version:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.7 --distribution-type=all
```

or explicitly set Google's Maven repository, instead of

```
google()
```

write

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```